# Regex for notepad++ to exclude hyphen

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to do a search in notepad++ for field `ProductGroup` out of my data, I need to find `Product` which do not have `-` (hyphen) in their `ProductGroup` name. Usually these are  `ProductGroup` names are

```
"ProductGroup": "Wels-RC"
"ProductGroup": "Wels-OC"
"ProductGroup": "RBE-RC"
"ProductGroup": "WXE-TN"
```

Can anyone help me how can I write `Regular Expression` to find `ProductGroup`'s records without `-`?

Comment: You can't match disjoint sequences of text into a single match, or group, within one match operation. Remove hyphens there first, then extract.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thanks for your input. If I will remove hyphens then all `ProductGroup` will the same(w/o -). How will it maintain the previous state? so that based on it I will extract the intended one

Comment: Then extract what you need and then remove. What is the problem here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - If I remove only  _hyphens_ first, from all values of key `ProductGroup`. Then `ProductGroup` with (-) and without (-) will be mixed in same file. `Then extract what you need - how?`.  `and then remove - That I can do it`. I have 58k records, out of it 1400 are w/o (-).  hope its clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try, below regex

```
"ProductGroup": "[^-]*?"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m0mApo/1)